# Selecting a custom QGraphicsItem by its outline

Tags: resize, border, qgraphicsitem, outline

What is the best way to resize a QGaphicsItem by grabbing its outline with the mouse and dragging. The program has a number of Qgraphicsitems on the scene and these can overlap or be inside one an other. The items are transparent drawing objects like rectangles, lines and circles.

I would like to be able to only select on the items border/outline. Is this possible?

Thanks